# How to create instance in for loop?

Tags: dart, flutter

I fetched data from API. storing data is very slow because inside my `for` loop insert data. How to create its instance before `for` loop or in class level?

```
storeWoDescription(String url,String token) async {
  final response = await http.get(
    '${url}/v1.0/WoDescription',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'},);
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  WoDescription model = WoDescription.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  int length = model.data.length;

  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var data = DataWoDescription(
      i: model.data[i].i,
      d: model.data[i].d,
      e: model.data[i].e,
      w: model.data[i].w,
      a: model.data[i].a,
      r: model.data[i].r,
      t: model.data[i].t,
      du: model.data[i].du,
      s: model.data[i].s,
      ra: model.data[i].ra,
      cul: model.data[i].cul,
    );
    await HelperDefCatMaster().insertWoDescription(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a better way to instantiate your database helper.

```
var helper;

void main() async {
  helper = await HelperDefCatMaster(); // instantiate it just once and use it everywhere. 
}

storeWoDescription(String url, String token) async {

  final response = await http.get(
    '${url}/v1.0/WoDescription',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'},
  );
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  WoDescription model = WoDescription.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  int length = model.data.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var data = DataWoDescription(
      i: model.data[i].i,
      d: model.data[i].d,
      e: model.data[i].e,
      w: model.data[i].w,
      a: model.data[i].a,
      r: model.data[i].r,
      t: model.data[i].t,
      du: model.data[i].du,
      s: model.data[i].s,
      ra: model.data[i].ra,
      cul: model.data[i].cul,
    );
    await helper.insertWoDescription(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I added helper in my main method, but when using `await helper.insertWoDescription(data);` in function **helper is null**

Comment: after click button i called function like this: `await HelperDefCatMaster().deleteWoDescription();
                              await storeWoDescription(_url,tokens);` **Is it correct way?**

Comment: still slow. why is that

Comment: First, the helper should not be `null` for sure. I don't know how you did that and did you miss something. Second, the solution I posted is a good practice of initialising database, so don't use your 2nd comment. Don't instantiate it in for loop, don't use `HelperDefCatMaster()` everywhere. It should be just one time call.

Comment: where do I call this function? storeWoDescription()

Comment: I used 2nd comment after press button

Comment: where do I call this function? storeWoDescription() -- You can do that wherever you need. You don't have to instantiate your Database over and over again. Just try to follow what I used. It is all you need.